# HTML 5 Canvas Hide?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Is there an event that can be used to hide the canvas after it plays its animation?  I have a canvas animation that plays then rests. I then want to use JavaScript to hide the canvas and show a static image with more intricate image swaps and linking than I know how to do in the canvas.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Set its `.style.display` to `'none'`?

Comment: yeah, that's the style I would target.  actually, I was going to use jquery hide() and show(), but i need to know what event to attach the function to so it will hide appropriately.

Comment: attach it to `$('canvas')`

Comment: Well, it depends on how you’ve created your canvas animation.

Comment: @minitech it is actually a fla that was converted to a canvas using Flash

Comment: Ditto what @minitech said.  We'll need to see code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not, because the HTML5 canvas API has no such concept like an animation. Everything that happens on a HTML5 canvas is the result of your script code changing the canvas content, so you should know best when you are finished changing it and no more changes are going to happen.

In a comment you said that you didn't write your canvas code yourself but used a tool to convert a flash animation to Javascript. So your options are:

1. You could try to understand the generated code and how to modify it to hide the canvas after it did the last thing it will do.
2. When the animation isn't interactive, you could use `setTimeout` to hide the canvas after a fixed time-period
3. You could consult the documentation of the tool you used. Maybe it has an option for doing this.
4. When it has no such option, you could bother the developers to add one, or when it is an open source tool, add such an option yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Ultimately what I had ended up doing was adding a timeout 5 seconds in a document.ready wrapper for. The worst thing that happens with this is if the end user has a slow connection, the image might show before the animation is done, but it was preferable to redoing the conversion process to build the action in. No where in the API generated code allowed me to do what I needed, it always hid the canvas immediately.